# Modify function Shortcode_atts

Tags: functions, shortcode

```
function get_date_posts($params, $content){
        $default_params = array(
            'post_type'     => 'post',
            'order'         => 'asc',
            'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
            'posts_per_page'=> 5,
            'meta_key'      => 'fl_date_picker'
        );

        if (isset($params['type']) && !empty($params['type']) && post_type_exists($params['type']))
            $params['post_type'] = $params['type'];

        if (isset($params['taxonomy']) && !empty($params['taxonomy']) && taxonomy_exists($params['taxonomy']) 
            && isset($params['slug']) && !empty($params['slug']))
            $params[$params['taxonomy']] = $params['slug'];



        foreach(array('type', 'slug', 'taxonomy') as $key)
            if (isset($params[$key]))
                unset($params[$key]);

        $params = wp_parse_args($params, $default_params);

        $params['meta_query'] = array( array(
                'key' => $params['meta_key'],
                'value' => date("Ymd"),
                'compare' => '>=',
                'type'=> 'date'
            )
        );

        $transient_hash = 'get_date_posts_'.substr(md5(serialize($params)),0,10);



        if (false === ($html = get_transient($transient_hash))){
            add_filter('query', 'q');
            global $request_sql;

            // init
            $html = '';

            $rp = new WP_Query($params);
        //  $html .= '<h2>START</h2>';
        //  $html .= '<pre>'.var_export($params, 1).'</pre>';
        //  $html .= $request_sql.'<hr>';

    if ($rp->have_posts()){

                $html .= '<ul>';
                while ( $rp->have_posts() ) { 
                    $rp->the_post(); 
                    $html .= "<li>";

                    if (($thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id())){
                        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'panel-small', false);
                        $flag = get_field('fl_country');
                        $html .= "<a href=".get_permalink()."><div id=\"calimgf\" style=\"background:url({$thumb['0']}) no-repeat left top;\">";
                        $html .= "<span id=\"loullos\" style=\"float:right;\" class='". $flag ."' >" ."</span>";
                    }
                    $html .= "<span class=\"calendate\" >".get_field('fl_event_date')."</span>";
                    $html .= "<span class=\"calenhead\" >".get_field('fl_event_title')."</span>";

                    //  debug   
                    //  $html .= "<small>".get_post_meta(get_the_id(), $params['meta_key'], 1)."</small>";

                    $html .= "</div></a></li>";
                }
                $html .= '</ul>';
            }

            if (!empty($html))
                set_transient($transient_hash, $html, 60);

        }
        return $html;
    }
```

The function above sorts posts by date using a custom field `'fl_date_picker'`

I need to modify this function so that the user specifies the number of posts to show in the shortcode. For that I tried using:

```
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'post_type'     => 'post',
            'order'         => 'asc',
            'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
            'posts_per_page'=> 5,
            'meta_key'      => 'fl_date_picker'
    ), $atts ) );
```

However the `fl_date_picker` does no longer work if I do this and post order is not retained.

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing [`shortcode_atts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/shortcode_atts).

1. You need to pass the shortcode an array of defaults in the first
   argument, which you have done.
2. Then you need to pass the user supplied arguments in the second
   argument, which you *haven't* done. Your shortcode callback uses
   `$params` yet for some reason you are passing `$atts`, which is not
   defined in your function.

Additionally, you are using [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/extract) with will create variables out of the supplied array. However, your code is not written to use those extracted variables. It still uses `$params`. `extract()` is, in my opinion, a confusing way to write code. Stick with `$params`.

Proof of concept:

```
function my_sc_cb($params = '') {
  $params = shortcode_atts( 
    array(
      'post_type'     => 'post',
      'order'         => 'asc',
      'orderby'       => 'meta_value',
      'posts_per_page'=> 5,
      'meta_key'      => 'fl_date_picker'
    ),
    $params
  );
  var_dump($params); // debugging
}
add_shortcode('msccb','my_sc_cb');
do_shortcode('[msccb post_type="page"]');
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn't work. I get an empty result instead. I have tried various ways of calling the shortcode but i always get empty results: `[get_date_posts type="os_calendar" taxonomy="calendar_event_type" slug="tennis" posts_per_page="5" meta_key="fl_date_picker"]`

Comment: Read the docs for `shortcode_atts`. The defaults have to match up with the attributes you are using.